# В отчете не выводится информация из декораторов Allure

Tags: python, selenium, test-automation, pytest, allure

Пишу автотесты, и теперь хочу вывести отчет в Allure, навесил декораторы, но почему то в отчете информация из них не выводится

```
class TestAccountMoves:
    # тест вхoда в вккаунт
    @allure.title('Проверка авторизации валидного юзера')
    @allure.description('Вход в аккаунт с валидными данными')
    def test_move_to_account_from_main_page(self, driver):
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы информация из декораторов Allure отображалась в отчете, необходимо выполнить следующие шаги:

Установить Allure командной строкой:

```
pip install allure-python-commons
```

Добавить декораторы Allure к тестовым методам: `@allure.step`

Запустить тесты с помощью команды:

```
allure generate <directory_with_results> -o <directory_with_report>
```

Открыть отчет с помощью команды `allure report open`

Если вы выполнили эти шаги, но информация все еще не отображается, проверьте, что вы используете последнюю версию Allure